# ASP.NET Core Web API controller does not return correct data

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In Visual Studio 2019, I created an ASP.NET Core / angular project. I also added a model to create a Web API controller for CRUD operations with EF.

This is the model and controller code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BooksWebApiAng.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string Editorial { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and for controller

```
using BooksWebApiAng.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BooksWebApiAng.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BooksController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BookContext _context;
        private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        public BooksController(BookContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            books.Add(new Book
            {
                BookId = 101,
                Titulo = "Tit1",
                Autor = "Aut1",
                Editorial = "Edi1"
            });
            books.Add(new Book
            {
                BookId = 102,
                Titulo = "Tit2",
                Autor = "Aut2",
                Editorial = "Edit2"
            });
            books.Add(new Book
            {
                BookId = 104,
                Titulo = "Tit2",
                Autor = "Aut3",
                Editorial = "Edit3"
            });
        }

        // Get list
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetBooks()
        {
            var data = await _context.Books.ToListAsync();

            if (data == null)
                return NotFound("No record");

            return (data);
        }

        private async Task<List<Book>> DameBooks()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return books;
        }
}
```

Then in Visual Studio with IIS Express, when a call `http://localhost/books` occurs, the code returns a list with all books in the `book` table.

But when I publish to IIS 10, it doesn't do that, it returns an error trying parsing home page to json.

But if I change this line

```
var data = await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
```

to

```
var data = await DameBooks();
```

that just return the list books it works correctly in both IIS Express and IIS 10.

I really don't have any idea what happen, because debugging in both cases "data" variable had a list with object book.

Thanks

Comment: This might be a simple as a connection string being incorrect when you deploy the application. Could you show the error being returned?

Comment: It's a sqllite database, so just datasource=booksdb.db. Website is on https://bookswebapiang.azurewebsites.net/ is an "error parsing character at 0..."because it looks like backend/web api  return home page and try parse like it was json. Thanks. ( thinking about dB connection I am not on computer where developing, so it could be that if database isn't copied over IIS server or I need like you says write correct path to sqllite dB.

Comment: A similar problem might be occurring because the IIS worker process does not have permission to access the sqllite db. Post stack trace or the error page that is being emitted by the call.

Comment: Yes it was that, I forgot upload my sqllite file to folder where website is published. Setting a correct path in datasource to this file and finally get website working right. Thanks for your help.